# Blackberry Webworks project not deploying to the blackberry simulator

Tags: eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am working on a project that compiles just fine without any errors in the console or error log.  All of the .cod files are signed in the process of building and all are marked as successfully signed. After the project build succeeds the blackberry simulator loads up as it should.  However the project is not actually loaded into the simulator and placed in the downloads.

If I have the simulator open when the build succeeds, the simulator will display the loading circle icon in the middle of the screen but never perform any actions.  I have tried cleaning the simulator and restarting my machine

I am using eclipse and working with phonegap and jquery mobile for this project.  I have tried the simulator on the Torch 9800 and the Bold 9700.  I would assume run time errors would show somewhere in the console but yet nothing new is showing up there or in the command prompt screen.

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT

After looking into the build folder inside of the solution, the zipped folder is there however there is no StandardInstall or OTAInstall folder.  The standard install folder would normally contain the .alx .cod .cls and .cso files for the project. I am assuming those are important and not sure why they are missing??